# why have to write c## for user creation in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

I have tried to create user accounts in oracle 12c. But it has shown the error:

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name.

I have tried the following two user name:

```
BANNER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> CREATE USER A3 IDENTIFIED BY p3;
CREATE USER A3 IDENTIFIED BY p3
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name


SQL> CREATE USER testUser IDENTIFIED BY pass;
CREATE USER testUser IDENTIFIED BY pass
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name


SQL> CREATE USER c##testUser IDENTIFIED BY pass;

User created.

SQL>
```

Then I have googled and found a solution that I have to write c## before the user name.

The reason is not clear to me. Can you please clear it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You have a container database and you are in the `CDB$ROOT` container.

In the root container, you can create only common users.

[Local Users in a CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#GUID-44E8518A-E02C-429C-9B06-16078EB3251A)

> A local user cannot be created in the root.

The name of common users must start with `c##`.

[Common Users in a CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#GUID-19337B94-645B-45E8-842C-762BBC544B13)

> "The name of every user-created common user must begin with the
>   characters c## or C##. (Oracle-supplied common user names do not have
>   this restriction.)"

For an overview of users in a container database, read [Overview of Commonality in a CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89257)

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/users.htm#DBSEG002):

> When you create a common user account, be aware of restrictions such
>   as where you can create these accounts, their naming conventions, and
>   the kinds of objects that can be stored in their schemas ...
>
> ... The name that you give the common user must start with C## or c##
>   and contain only ASCII or EDCDIC characters. (This requirement does
>   not apply to the names of existing Oracle-supplied user accounts, such
>   as SYS or SYSTEM.)

It's essentially because you've created a multitenant capable database, and are trying to create a user in the root.

Read up on multitenant - [documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89235).